# Liferay not creating tables in phpmyadmin Database

Tags: phpmyadmin, liferay

I've just created a brand new phpmyadmin  Liferay Database. The database is empty and I'm trying to have Liferay populate it with the proper tables on Tomcat's startup.

Comment: Did you verify that Liferay is using your database? The default (if nothing was configured) is an internal hsqldb.  Depending on your Liferay version, please check the documentation how to use an external Database. If already done, there is maybe something in your server log about database connection details on startup.

Comment: i m using liferay 7.1 and all credential of external database is provided like username,password etc.query is also generated but Liferay doesnot  populate it with the proper tables on Tomcat's startup.

Comment: Liferay requires the existence of a database (and the required tables) for its work. If your database is still empty, then liferay is using a different database (If it starts properly). Please verify your configuration, for a simple jdbc setup please check: [portal.properties.html#JDBC](https://docs.liferay.com/ce/portal/7.1-latest/propertiesdoc/portal.properties.html#JDBC)